How to pass known schemas when parsing an Avro schema to avoid SchemaParseException?
I'm trying to pass a set of known schemas when parsing the TC.avsc schema to avoid schema dependencies issues. Below is the code I'm using:
from confluent_kafka import Producer
from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroProducer
from confluent_kafka.avro import CachedSchemaRegistryClient
from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer import SerializerError
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry.avro import AvroSerializer
from avro.schema import parse
import json

schema_dir = '/home/jupyter/kafka/schemas'

schema_files = [
    'cm/sc1.avsc',
    'cm/sc2.avsc',
    'dt/sc3.avsc',
    'dt/sc4.avsc',
    'dt/sc5.avsc',
    'dt/sc6.avsc',
    'dt/sc7.avsc',
    'dt/sc8.avsc'
]

# Dictionary to hold known schemas (without parsing)
known_schemas = {schema_file: None for schema_file in schema_files}

# Load the TransactionContext schema for sending messages
transaction_schema_path = f'{schema_dir}/TC.avsc'
with open(transaction_schema_path, 'r') as f:
    transaction_schema_str = f.read()
    transaction_schema_data = json.loads(transaction_schema_str)
    
    # Parse the TransactionContext schema while passing known_schemas
    transaction_schema = parse(json.dumps(transaction_schema_data), known_schemas)

However, when I run this, I encounter the following error:
SchemaParseException: Type property "com.sc.db.lib.tracking.Flow" not a valid Avro schema: Could not make an Avro Schema object from com.sc.db.lib.tracking.Flow

It seems like it's unable to resolve some dependencies from the known_schemas. How can I pass the known_schemas correctly while parsing the TC.avsc to avoid such schema dependency issues? Any suggestions on how to resolve this error?
